# Getting the path of the virtualenv's site-packages with Python

Tags: python, virtualenv

So I am trying to find the path to the files that are installed with the requirements.txt to use in my code.
Currently I am getting it like this:

```
library_path = os.getcwd() + '/.app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/'
```

This doesn't look like a proper way to get there, what are the alternatives to get to this path that will work on other machines as well?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this gets the correct path:
library_path = get_python_lib()